# Как указать пути в csv файлах используя flask

Tags: python, css, flask, jinja

Писал страничку на чистых html и css, потом это всё хотел использовать с фреймворков flask, но появились проблемы со ссылками и путями.

Ошибка: "GET /images/bg_pick_2.png HTTP/1.1" 404

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url(/images/bg_pick_2.png);
  background-size: 100% 1046px;
}
```

Comment: Логично, что ссылка должна указывать в то место, которое способно отдать нужный вам ответ. Что вы предприняли для того, чтобы по ссылке `/images/bg_pick_2.png` отдавалось то, что вы хотите?